In Matching, are capped confounders a legitimate method of improving balance for matching with highly skewed continuous confounders?
In matching (or similar confounder-control methods such as weighting), are "capped metrics" a "legitimate" method of improving balance for highly-skewed continuous confounders?
Capped metrics are a commonly used variance-reduction method in online experimentation (Kohavi et al., 2014), but is used on the outcome variable (I'm not familiar if capping is used in CUPED). Capping is when you take all values after a certain percentile (e.g., 99) to be the same. Ultimately I understand that it's a bias-variance trade-off and that balance-reduction methods already exist such as calipers (a trade-off of bias), but in some scenarios I felt that capping would be justified too when dealing with very high skew (>20+ skewness coefficient) due to extreme right tails but I wanted to check if there was some justification from the literature so that I don't use invalid methods (I was not able to find anything about this topic yet).

The relationship between imbalance and bias depends on the potential outcome-generating model. If the outcome model is of the form
$$
Y^a = \beta_0 + \tau a + \beta_1 X + \varepsilon
$$
then balance on the mean of $X$ is required for unbiased estimation of the treatment effect ($\tau$) using the difference-in-means estimator after matching. If the outcome model is of the form
$$
Y^a = \beta_0 + \tau a + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 X^2 + \varepsilon
$$
then balance on the mean of $X$ and the mean of $X^2$ is required for unbiased estimation of the treatment effect. This has nothing to do with how skewed $X$ is. If you cap $X$, i.e., turn it into a variable $X^*$, then balance on $X^*$ does not correspond exactly to balance on $X$, and adjusting for $X^*$ does not mean adjusting for $X$. So by capping $X$ in balance assessment to make your sample "look" more balanced, you are potentially missing out on real imbalance that needs to be addressed (i.e., imbalance in the tails). Similarly, it might be that including $X^*$ and not $X$ in your propensity score model produces a well-fitting propensity score and balances $X^*$ well, but if you need to achieve balance on $X$, then balance on $X^*$ is not sufficient.
If it is impossible to balance a covariate because it has a long tail in one treatment group and not the other, you may need to change your estimand to reflect this or commit to extrapolating beyond the region of common support between the groups.
Ultimately, because we don't know the true outcome model, we can't say for certain whether capping will lead to bias. It might be that the true outcome model involves a capped $X$, in which case it could be smart to cap it. But if the values in the tail are meaningful, they need to be taken seriously and not recoded. It could be that the model you use to adjust for $X$ involves a capped $X$, but balance needs to be assessed on the terms as they enter the outcome model.

thanks for the explanation. so would you say that if the researcher feels that the values of below the 99th percentile is meaningfully more important than above the 99th percentile (for example, a value of 1 vs 4 is very meaningful but a difference of the extremely rare 20000 vs 40000 is not meaningful, then capping could be convincing to the audience? from what i understand, in matching / weighting, all value differences are treated equal, right? (2 vs 4 is treated the same as 20 vs 22 although (depending on the problem) 2 vs 4 is often more significant than 20 vs 22)

You need to convince your audience that extreme tails are not important for the outcome, so that, yes, 20000 vs 40000 is not meaningful. If there is a linear or quadratic relationship between the covariate and the outcome, then bias will remain if you fail to balance the tails, but if the relationship is like $Y = \beta_0 + \tau A + \beta_1 \log(X) + \varepsilon$, then differences in the tails are less important.
